# Find insert position and number of childs in a binary tree using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

below is my table data

```
+-------------+-----------+----------------+
| customer_id | parent_id | node_direction |
+-------------+-----------+----------------+
|           1 |         0 | T              |
|           2 |         1 | L              |
|           3 |         1 | R              |
|           4 |         2 | L              |
|           5 |         2 | R              |
|           6 |         4 | L              |
+-------------+-----------+----------------+
Which represents the following tree
                      1
                      |
                  ---------
                  |       |
                  2       3
                  |
               -------
               |     |  
               4     5
               |
             -----
             |
             6
```

I need to find the position for insertion by parent id

For Example:

1) if parent id is 1 then insert position will be root-3 position-L
2) if parent_id is 2 then insert position will be root-4 position-R
3) if parent_id is 3 then insert position will be root-3 position-L

The thing is it need to follow the binary structure

I also need to have count of sub nodes by parent node for example:

```
1 - 5
2 - 3
3 - 0
4 - 1
5 - 0
```

I need to accomplish this in php and mysql.

Can anyone suggest to me the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getNodeInsertPostionByParentId($parentId){
        $position = array('status'=>false);
        $parents = array();
        foreach($parentId as $parent){              
                $qry = "select customer_id,node_direction from mlm_nodes where parent_id =".$parent." order by node_direction";
                $rst = mysql_query($qry);
                $count = mysql_num_rows($rst);
                if($count==2){
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rst)){
                        $parents[$parent][] = $row['customer_id'];
                    }   
                }elseif($count==1){
                    $position['status'] = true;
                    $position['parentId'] = $parent;
                    $position['node'] = 'R';
                    //echo '<pre>1';print_r($position);echo '</pre>';
                    return $position;
                }else{
                    $position['status'] = true;
                    $position['parentId'] = $parent;
                    $position['node'] = 'L';
                    //echo '<pre>2';print_r($position);echo '</pre>';
                    return $position;
                }
            }

        return $this->searchByParents($parents);
    }

    function searchByParents($parents){

        foreach($parents as $parent){
            return $this->getNodeInsertPostionByParentId($parent);  
        }
    } 


echo '<pre>';print_r($this->getNodeInsertPostionByParentId(array('4')));die;
```

This works as expected for finding node position by parent id